# Why is not Fasting Punished so harshly?

Tags: practical-islam, sin, sawm, ramadan, punishment

This has been on my mind for a while. It's said that as Muslims we fast during the blessed month of Ramadan to achieve a greater closeness to Allah and better ourselves as muslims and people. So then why is it that if somebody chooses to leave their fast they are punished so harshly by Allah? Surely it's their loss and while I don't encourage leaving fasts I'm a little confused as to why not fasting is punished so severely since as long as they are not leaving their fasts to sin and they still pray 5 times a day they are not doing anything "wrong" there is just a lack of them doing "rightful" things so they miss out on sawab at their own loss.

Comment: You should explain what do you mean by punished so harshly. What is the punishment you are talking about? What is the basis of your claim(Source?)? In this question you make a claim and didn't provide any explanation on what you are referring to!

Answer (score 0):

I mean it’s one of the 5 pillars which sets the foundations for a Muslim and if one of those pillars is “broken” then you lose your desire to be a good Muslim. And Allah has blessed us with the month of Ramadan so not fasting is kind of insulting as Allah did not have to give us this blessed month, so we should do our best and fast and pray as much as we can during this period.